# Issue in pagination angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, pagination

I am having an issue with pagination : 
This is my html

```
    <div class="panel panel-info" ng-repeat="item in filteredTodos | orderBy: 'Date' : true | filter : search">
     {{item.Name}}
    </div>
<div data-pagination="" data-num-pages="numPages()" 
      data-current-page="currentPage" data-max-size="maxSize"  
      data-boundary-links="true"></div>
```

and this is my controller :

```
$scope.filteredTodos = []
  $scope.currentPage = 1
  $scope.numPerPage = 4
  $scope.maxSize = 5

  $scope.makeTodos = function() {
    $scope.Offre = [];
    $http({
                header: 'content-type:application/json',
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/GetOffre',
            }).success(function (messages) {
            $scope.Offre =messages  ;
      });

  };
  $scope.makeTodos(); 

  $scope.numPages = function () {
    return Math.ceil($scope.Offre.length / $scope.numPerPage);
  };

  $scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function() {
    var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage)
    , end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;

    $scope.filteredTodos = $scope.Offre.slice(begin, end);
  });
```

so the problem is when i want to show my result 
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04hH3.png)

i tried to change the currentPage = 0 so in view i can click in 1 and i can see the result only when i click on 1... and when i refresh the page the same issue is repeated

Comment: currentPage must start from 1 i suppose. If you want to test it, add more data or shrink page size small enough to have more than 1 page

Answer (score 0):

Use limitto in you ng-repeat it's better than $watch

```
<div class="panel panel-info" ng-repeat="item in filteredTodos | orderBy: 'Date' : true | filter : search"|limitTo:(($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage):$scope.numPerPage*$scope.currentPage>
 {{item.Name}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily in the template by using the built-in **`limitTo`** filter.

```
<div class="panel panel-info" ng-repeat="item in Offre | limitTo : maxSize : (currentPage * maxSize - maxSize)">
    <!-- print your item details here -->
</div>
```

Then you can add buttons (previous, next, atd.) which would change the `currentPage` variable and thus changing the content displayed.